# how to implement an animation on segment of doughnut in chartjs

Tags: chart.js

i tried to do this:

```
const options: ChartOptions<"doughnut"> = {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        offset: 5,
        borderRadius: 3,
        animations: {
            backgroundColor: {
                duration: 500,
                type: "color",
                easing: "linear",
                to: "transparent",
                from: "#ff5722",
                loop: true,
            },
        }}
```

but it works for the all chart, help me please

Comment: You can use the fact that the `animations` property `backgroundColor` is [scriptable](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/options.html#scriptable-options), here's [an example](https://jsfiddle.net/jb7y3sx2/).